# Electrical Issue with over heating-2008 PT Cruiser

Tags: overheating, radiator, leak, chrysler, pt-cruiser

In October 2018 I purchased a 2008 PT Cruiser and immediately it overheated as I drove it home (purchased from a no warranty place). I took it to a shop that specializes in radiators and they concluded that the issue was electrical-the fan wasn't running; there were no leaks. That gentleman told me I would be ok in the winter as far as overheating but to have the electrical system checked in the spring. Well, spring is almost here so I made an appointment with a regular mechanic and specified an electrical issue informing them I had taken the car to the radiator shop. I checked the radiator 3 days ago and it was full, there are no signs of leaking where my car has been parked. This shop called me and informed me that the mounting unit that holds the radiator is broken and there is a huge hole in the radiator and fluid is pouring out. I barely drive the car, haven't hit anything; how is this possible?  Is it possible to have made it 5 months with a leak; but, the tank was full.  I am so baffled and I feel like they did something to the radiator.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'd take issue with it as well. From what you're telling me, it sounds nefarious.

Comment: When you say you barely drive the car, what does that mean?  When you do drive it, does the car have time to warm up to operating temperature?

Comment: By barely driving it I mean I live in a small town so the furthest I have to drive for errands is 5 miles; so maybe 30 miles a week.  The car does have time to warm to operating temperature.  I took it to an auto parts store today and removed the relays for the fan though the store's matching relay (per their system) didn't match the one I took out.  I cleaned corrosion off the male parts and put back in the car and it seems to not be over heating now.  I will see how it goes from here. Taking it to a radiator shop tomorrow to confirm the broken mounting part.

Comment: If you have no signs of leaks on your driveway or garage until recent service examination, be wary.